# comparing user input and list created by text file using in operator always returns false

Tags: python, list, input, boolean

Creating an access code program.  I created a list and placed the file in it.
The output is: ['Cameron', 'Cameron', 'sudocode', 'Sudocode'...] ect. That part is fine.

I have tried using many different methods, mainly the 'in' operator to get boolean value of True.  Never happens.  I type in 'Cameron' and I get back false.  Here is the code.

`

```
with open("kwaccess.txt") as file:
        keyword1 = file.read().splitlines()
        keyword_accesslist = [x.rstrip() for x in keyword1]
        print(keyword_accesslist)
```

## output is: ['Cameron', 'cameron', 'sudocode', 'Sudocode', 'Python or python']

```
for attempt in keyword_accesslist:
    print(verify1)`

# Another attempt
if attempt in keyword_accesslist:
    verify1 == True
else:
    verify1 == False
```

If I type in Cameron, which is in the list for certain or any of the keywords, I get back False 5 times (for the 5 elements in the list, then it moves on to next part of code.  Everything else works. Even the random number generator that I use the 'in' operator to compare with the user input and works perfect.  It's the file into a list that has the compare jacked up.  What am I missing...how do you compare a list element to the user string input with the 'in' operator.

I've gotten this error a few times during this long stretch of 'Denying' further coding day :)

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list...not currently, but along the way

Good luck Master coders.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
def code_generator(string):
    test = str(string) + str(randint(200,2000))
    return test

def list_random_true():
    codenumber = [number for number in range(200,2000)]
    return codenumber

def access_code(attempt):
    with open("kwaccess.txt") as file:
        keyword1 = file.read().splitlines()
        keyword_accesslist = [x.rstrip() for x in keyword1]
        print(keyword_accesslist)  # output is: ['Cameron',     'cameron', 'sudocode', 'Sudocode', 'Python or python']

    ##This is my PROBLEM AREA, can't rotate through the elements in list and compare against attempt
    verify1 = False
    for x in range(len(keyword_accesslist)):
        verify1 = attempt == str(keyword_accesslist[x])
        if verify1 == True:
            x = 1
            for x in range(3):
                print("Verifying...")
                time.sleep(3)
                break
        else:
            x += 1
            input("Access Denied.  Please re-enter password.  ")
            if x == 3:
                print("Your account has been locked.  Please contact Admin Services.") 
                exit()   
            else:
                pass

    numbercheck = str(list_random_true())   # Each number in own element to check
    for number in numbercheck:
        verify2 = number in attempt

        if verify2 == True: # Second Security Attemp
            print("Access Granted")
            break
        else:
           pass
```

BEGINNING OF PROGRAM

```
try:
    compare = input("Please enter Secret Code.  ")

except EOFError as e:
    pass

attempt = code_generator(compare)
access_code(attempt)
```

Comment: wait in your second example, is #another attempt part of the loop body?

Comment: Good question, no.  Just explaining, that was another version of me trying to get it to work, still producing only 'False'.

Comment: cameron, can you post your entire program that is causing the error?

Comment: Ok @Yolomep I have added the code.  Thanks for the look.  As I said, if I just don't pull in from file and hardcode in attempt, it all works fine...I just can't get the list to parse and compare string by string against the user input.

Comment: Thanks Yolomep!  It didn't quite work, but I modified 'verify1 = attempt **in** password', the == was an accident, then I switched the order of password and attempt...password in attempt.  It WORKED, almost!  So I broke it down further, made another function for first code check and I have all of it working!! except the 'if false, re-enter password part'.  Thanks for your help!! The problem WAS needing while loop to work through each element as it went through the 'in' statement.  Why did you say it would be a debugging problem?  Confused on that...what makes it a debug issue verses code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I checked out your code. With what you have, I do not understand what you are doing. `verify1 = attempt == keyword_accesslist[x]` will always return false as attempt is attempt is the user input but with some random digits appended to it, which is never the first element of keyword_accesslist. In addition, are you trying to check each word in keyword_accesslist and see if the attempt is equal or just the first element? Because you only iterate once every x, then if the check is wrong it will print "access denied" *THEN* check the next keyword_accesslist.

With some guesses, I think this is similiar to what you want:

```py
    verify1 = False
    tries = 0
    while tries < 3:
        for password in keyword_accesslist:
            verify1 = attempt == password
            if verify1:
                for x in range(3):
                    print("Verifying...")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    break
        if not verify1:
            tries += 1
            attempt = input("Access Denied.  Please re-enter password.  ")
            if tries == 3:
                print("Your account has been locked.  Please contact Admin Services.") 
                exit()
```

It's not the best, but I have changed the loop so that it probably does what you want it to do. It uses a nested loop to check for the password and the outer while loop to keep track of tries. I've attempted to use your logic, but I don't understand some of your other functions.

This feels like a debugging problem and not suited for stackoverflow, but I hope that you recieved the help you need.